# What is a context free action?

Tags: smart-contract

I have been doing some digging into the system smart contracts and eosio core code, and I found context free actions. Can somebody please explain what the difference between a context free action and a normal action is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: **context free actions do not depend upon the blockchain state to perform validation**

---

More:

> A context free action involves computations that depend only on
>   transaction data. **A primary example of such a computation is signature
>   validation.** Given only the transaction data and a signature we can
>   compute the public key that signed the transaction. This computation
>   is one of the most expensive individual computations a blockchain must
>   perform. Because this computation is context free (doesn’t depend upon
>   blockchain state), it can be performed in parallel.
>
> Context free actions are like other user actions, except they lack
>   access to the blockchain state to perform validation. This enables
>   EOSIO to process all context free actions in parallel just like
>   signature verification. More importantly, this enables generalized
>   signature verification.

Source | https://medium.com/@bytemaster/eosio-development-update-272198df22c1

[Also from White Paper](https://github.com/EOSIO/Documentation/blob/master/TechnicalWhitePaper.md#context-free-actions)